# How to use Docker with the difficult structured Flet project?

Tags: python, docker, web-applications, flet

My project has this structure:

```
-main_flet_app.py
-app1_folder:
 flet_app.py
-app2_folder:
 flet_app.py
```

From main_flet_app.py I run other apps using module subprocess, this is necessary in order to open every app in new browser tab. But I have problems, then I make container in Docker.

Then I run container, main_flet_app run other apps, but it can't open new browser tab.

What can I do?
Maybe you can say how to change project structure? But for me important to open new app in new tab. maybe it's possible to do with routing.

P.S. Each app has its own port.